# Error when installing xml2 package on Mavericks

Tags: r, libxml2, devtools

I'm trying to install devtools package in R, and as its dependency xml2 needs to be installed, but I'm getting the following error message.

```
> install.packages("xml2")
Installing package into ‘/Users/xlong3/Library/R/3.2/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xml2_0.1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 74808 bytes (73 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 73 KB

* installing *source* package ‘xml2’ ...
** package ‘xml2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/Users/xlong3/anaconda/include/libxml2
Using PKG_LIBS=-L/Users/xlong3/anaconda/lib -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm
** libs
clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Users/xlong3/anaconda/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I"/Users/xlong3/Library/R/3.2/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/BH/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Users/xlong3/anaconda/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I"/Users/xlong3/Library/R/3.2/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/BH/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c connection.cpp -o connection.o
clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Users/xlong3/anaconda/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I"/Users/xlong3/Library/R/3.2/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/BH/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c xml2_doc.cpp -o xml2_doc.o
clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Users/xlong3/anaconda/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I"/Users/xlong3/Library/R/3.2/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/BH/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c xml2_init.cpp -o xml2_init.o
clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Users/xlong3/anaconda/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I"/Users/xlong3/Library/R/3.2/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/BH/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c xml2_namespace.cpp -o xml2_namespace.o
clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Users/xlong3/anaconda/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I"/Users/xlong3/Library/R/3.2/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/BH/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c xml2_node.cpp -o xml2_node.o
clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Users/xlong3/anaconda/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I"/Users/xlong3/Library/R/3.2/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/BH/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c xml2_url.cpp -o xml2_url.o
clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Users/xlong3/anaconda/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I"/Users/xlong3/Library/R/3.2/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/BH/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c xml2_xpath.cpp -o xml2_xpath.o
clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Users/xlong3/anaconda/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I"/Users/xlong3/Library/R/3.2/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/BH/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c xml_push.cpp -o xml_push.o
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -o xml2.so RcppExports.o connection.o xml2_doc.o xml2_init.o xml2_namespace.o xml2_node.o xml2_url.o xml2_xpath.o xml_push.o -L/Users/xlong3/anaconda/lib -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm -F/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/.. -framework R -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Users/xlong3/Library/R/3.2/library/xml2/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Users/xlong3/Library/R/3.2/library/xml2/libs/xml2.so':
  dlopen(/Users/xlong3/Library/R/3.2/library/xml2/libs/xml2.so, 6): Library not loaded: libxml2.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/xlong3/Library/R/3.2/library/xml2/libs/xml2.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Users/xlong3/Library/R/3.2/library/xml2’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/tmp/RtmpJc4WKq/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("xml2") :
  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
>




> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0                                              
version.string R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
nickname       Fire Safety
```

Comment: While `configure` found `libxml2` something else is awry. It could be a `PATH` issue but you've got an interesting setup. Since you are using Homebrew for R why aren't you using Homebrew for `libxml2`? I'd install `libxml2` from Homebrew, remove Anaconda from the `PATH` and then re-try the build.

Comment: Yes I did home-brew libxml2:  brew install libxml2
Warning: libxml2-2.9.2 already installed   , It's not working.

Comment: that may be the case but it's finding it at `/Users/xlong3/anaconda/include/libxml2` so you've got a really confused setup.

Comment: I reset PATH as PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin  :    echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin       But while I install.packages("xml2"), it's still telling me that it's finding it at  /Users/xlong3/anaconda/include/libxml2 .   Where is likely the config file and can I change where it find libxml2?

Comment: it's running pkg-config (or pkgconfig i never remember which) in configure. did you restart R after resetting the PATH?

Comment: > pkg-config --libs --cflags  libxml2
Package libxml2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxml2' found

Comment: download the xml2 package source from github and run the configure script in the main pkg directory (or look at it). you've got kind of a weird config (assuming anaconda is for python / jupyter). i'd nuke anaconda and use homebrew for python/jupyter since you're doing that for R anyway.

Comment: oddly I completed remove the anaconda , also remove a config file   /usr/bin/xml2-config which I have no idea how did it get generated, and then when in install.packages("xml2") it know to find libxml2 at its positions    that specified by the "brew ls libxml2".    SOOOOOOOO tired!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that 'pkg-config' is looking specifically for 'libxml2.pc' and the file that you have installed is named, "libxml-2.0.pc".  If you manually create a symbolic link between the existing file and the one pkg-config expects, it should resolve that error.

Something like this (done in the same directory as the file) should work

`$ ln -s libxml-2.0.pc libxml2.pc`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how should I proceed from the following situation:

> ```
>    pkg-config --libs --cflags  libxml2
> ```
>
> Package libxml2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml2.pc'
>   to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'libxml2' found
>
> brew ls libxml2

```
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/bin/xml2-config
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/bin/xmlcatalog
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/bin/xmllint
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/include/libxml2/ (47 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/lib/cmake/libxml2/libxml2-config.cmake
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/lib/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/lib/ (3 other files)
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/share/aclocal/libxml.m4
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/share/doc/ (153 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/share/gtk-doc/ (55 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/share/man/ (4 files)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your CRAN mirror